# Are the AWS MTurk Sandbox WorkerIDs the same as Production WorkerIDs

Tags: mechanicalturk

I want to notify workers (that have a certain qualification of upcoming work), using the Python SDK. If I use the list of workers from the 'Production' environment in the 'Sandbox' environment, will the 'Production' workers get the notification even though it is send within the 'Sandbox'?

Thanks

PS I am aware that qualification-type-ids are not transferable between 'Sandbox' and 'Production'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are the same in production and sandbox.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply, could you confirm that messages send when connected to the sandbox will be send to 'production' users.

Comment: Assuming you're referring to things like NotifyWorker(), but in any event yes they will, though the messages will explicitly say that they are coming from Sandbox.

Comment: Yes I meant through NotifyWorker().